# Why does this app give me "Unfortunately, your app has stopped"?

Tags: php, android, authentication

This is my code for a login system except the PHP file does not seem to login. I want to fix the main problem first and I will modify the PHP file to get user from database.

login.java:

```
public class login extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

private EditText usernameEditText;
private EditText passwordEditText;
private Button sendPostReqButton;
private Button clearButton;

 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.login);

    usernameEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
    passwordEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);

    sendPostReqButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login);
    sendPostReqButton.setOnClickListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if(v.getId() == R.id.login){
        String givenUsername = usernameEditText.getEditableText().toString();
        String givenPassword = passwordEditText.getEditableText().toString();

        System.out.println("Given username :" + givenUsername + " Given password :" + givenPassword);

        sendPostRequest(givenUsername, givenPassword);
    }   
}

private void sendPostRequest(String givenUsername, String givenPassword) {

    class SendPostReqAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            String paramUsername = params[0];
            String paramPassword = params[1];

            System.out.println("*** doInBackground ** paramUsername " + paramUsername + " paramPassword :" + paramPassword);

            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();


            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://www.nirmana.lk/hec/android/postLogin.php");

            BasicNameValuePair usernameBasicNameValuePair = new BasicNameValuePair("paramUsername", paramUsername);
            BasicNameValuePair passwordBasicNameValuePAir = new BasicNameValuePair("paramPassword", paramPassword);


            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairList = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            nameValuePairList.add(usernameBasicNameValuePair);
            nameValuePairList.add(passwordBasicNameValuePAir);

            try {

                UrlEncodedFormEntity urlEncodedFormEntity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairList);

                // setEntity() hands the entity (here it is urlEncodedFormEntity) to the request.
                httpPost.setEntity(urlEncodedFormEntity);

                try {
                    HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);



                    InputStream inputStream = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();

                    InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);

                    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);

                    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

                    String bufferedStrChunk = null;

                    while((bufferedStrChunk = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
                        stringBuilder.append(bufferedStrChunk);
                    }

                    return stringBuilder.toString();

                } catch (ClientProtocolException cpe) {
                    System.out.println("First Exception caz of HttpResponese :" + cpe);
                    cpe.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException ioe) {
                    System.out.println("Second Exception caz of HttpResponse :" + ioe);
                    ioe.printStackTrace();
                }

            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException uee) {
                System.out.println("An Exception given because of UrlEncodedFormEntity argument :" + uee);
                uee.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            if(result.equals("working")){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "HTTP POST is working...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Invalid POST req...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }           
    }

    SendPostReqAsyncTask sendPostReqAsyncTask = new SendPostReqAsyncTask();
    sendPostReqAsyncTask.execute(givenUsername, givenPassword);     
}
```

}

PHP file:

```
   <?php

   $varUsername = $_POST['paramUsername'];
   $varPassword = $_POST['paramPassword'];

   if($varUsername == "anuja" && $varPassword == "123"){
echo 'working';
   }else{
echo 'invalid';
    }

   ?>
```

I don't know why it has stopped?

Comment: on button click new SendPostReqAsyncTask().execute(params); and pass the values to doinbackground or to the constructor of the class.

Comment: @Raghunandan sorry but clarify it

Comment: Post the stacktrace, it can help easily and also save time.

Comment: @MohamedGamal if you don't know how to get logcat details check this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wPaUxCrp6qI around 1 to 2 minutes

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the values to doInbackground(param) or to the constructor of asynctask.

To load the asynctask

Pass the values to constructor

```
new SendPostReqAsyncTask(givenUsername, givenPassword).execute();
```

Check this http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html . check the topic under threading rules.

You can remove the method `sendPostRequest(givenUsername, givenPassword)` and make your asynctask inner class of your activity.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
        switch(v.getId())
        {
        case R.id.login:

        String givenUsername = usernameEditText.getEditableText().toString();
        String givenPassword = passwordEditText.getEditableText().toString();

        System.out.println("Given username :" + givenUsername + " Given password :" + givenPassword);

        new SendPostReqAsyncTask(givenUsername, givenPassword).execute(); 
         break;
         }

    }
    class SendPostReqAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

      String paramUsername;
      String paramPassword ;

      public SendPostReqAsyncTask(String name,String password)
       {
                paramUsername = name;
                paramPassword = password;
       }
       .... 
     }
```

Or

```
new SendPostReqAsyncTask().execute(givenUsername, givenPassword);
```

AsycTask

```
class SendPostReqAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String>
{

    String paramUsername;
    String paramPassword ;

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        paramUsername = params[0];
        paramPassword = params[1]; 
        .... 
        return "something";
    }

}
```

Edit:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

private EditText usernameEditText;
private EditText passwordEditText;
private Button sendPostReqButton;
private Button clearButton;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

   usernameEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
   passwordEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);

   sendPostReqButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
   sendPostReqButton.setOnClickListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
      switch(v.getId())
      {
      case R.id.button1:
       String givenUsername = usernameEditText.getEditableText().toString();
       String givenPassword = passwordEditText.getEditableText().toString();
       System.out.println("Given username :" + givenUsername + " Given password :" + givenPassword);
       new SendPostReqAsyncTask().execute(givenUsername, givenPassword); 
       break;  
      }
   }   


   class SendPostReqAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

       @Override
       protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

           String paramUsername = params[0];
           String paramPassword = params[1];

           System.out.println("*** doInBackground ** paramUsername " + paramUsername + " paramPassword :" + paramPassword);

           HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
           HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://www.nirmana.lk/hec/android/postLogin.php");
           BasicNameValuePair usernameBasicNameValuePair = new BasicNameValuePair("paramUsername", paramUsername);
           BasicNameValuePair passwordBasicNameValuePAir = new BasicNameValuePair("paramPassword", paramPassword);
           List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairList = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
           nameValuePairList.add(usernameBasicNameValuePair);
           nameValuePairList.add(passwordBasicNameValuePAir);

           try {

               UrlEncodedFormEntity urlEncodedFormEntity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairList);

               // setEntity() hands the entity (here it is urlEncodedFormEntity) to the request.
               httpPost.setEntity(urlEncodedFormEntity);

               try {
                   HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                   InputStream inputStream = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();
                   InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
                   BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
                   StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                   String bufferedStrChunk = null;

                   while((bufferedStrChunk = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
                       stringBuilder.append(bufferedStrChunk);
                   }

                   return stringBuilder.toString();

               } catch (ClientProtocolException cpe) {
                   System.out.println("First Exception caz of HttpResponese :" + cpe);
                   cpe.printStackTrace();
               } catch (IOException ioe) {
                   System.out.println("Second Exception caz of HttpResponse :" + ioe);
                   ioe.printStackTrace();
               }

           } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException uee) {
               System.out.println("An Exception given because of UrlEncodedFormEntity argument :" + uee);
               uee.printStackTrace();
           }

           return null;
       }

       @Override
       protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
           super.onPostExecute(result);

           if(result.equals("working")){
               Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "HTTP POST is working...", 10000).show();
           }else{
               Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Invalid POST req...", 10000).show();
           }
       }           
   } 
}
```

activity_main.mxl

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
     >



    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Snap shot

[image]

Comment: How can I remove the sendPostRequest method ??

Comment: remove it manually. you don't need it

Comment: I'm new in android, so I get confused or may u write modified code . I'm sorry for that . Thanks

Comment: what part are you getting confused? Remove the method and use the above codes.

Comment: what about this part
   
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            if(result.equals("working")){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "HTTP POST is working...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Invalid POST req...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }           
    }
    SendPostReqAsyncTask sendPostReqAsyncTask = new SendPostReqAsyncTask();
    sendPostReqAsyncTask.execute(givenUsername, givenPassword);

Comment: i don't know what you are doing calling SendPostReqAsyncTask sendPostReqAsyncTask = new SendPostReqAsyncTask(); sendPostReqAsyncTask.execute(givenUsername, givenPassword);  in onPostExecute. i suggest you read the link in the answer first

Comment: but I get this code from the link and it works with others 
http://anujarosha.wordpress.com/2012/01/27/handling-http-post-method-in-android/

Comment: post your logcat for further assistance

Comment: also check the edit. i tried it on emulator. password field is visible change it. change the ids and keep the rest the same. it works

Comment: now there is no confusion i guess i have posted full code + snapshot. if you need further assistance ask a new question

Comment: I used the same code you edit but still same error :(

Comment: i can't help you any further until you post the logcat. by the way the above works tested it on emulator. If you don;t know how to modify the working code how can you expect someone to help you? You need to edit the ids and the class name. i have modified so that i can run and test on my emulator

Comment: where can i get the logcat to post it here

Comment: goto window in eclipse click open perspective. choose ddms logcat. there when you run you can get the details of the crash. you can export it to a text file and copy paste it here

Comment: 06-10 13:24:18.884: W/Trace(809): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0

Comment: post the full stack trace. i think you need to get your basics right. read the docs first. we can't help you with each and every task. If you can't modify the above. what else can we do. write the code for you?

Comment: what version you used to run this app

Comment: Why are you bothered about the version? the latest 4.2 on emulator. It has nothing to do with your code in this context

Comment: so what can i do now ?

Comment: modify the above according to your requirements if you can. if you can't get your basics right and try again. this is all i can do to assist you

Comment: Can u give me the full code with UI also ?

Comment: @MohamedGamal: I agree with Raghunandan, this is classic [help vampirism](http://slash7.com/2006/12/22/vampires/). Where you get some assistance, you need to then do some new research with the useful clues that have been provided to you. If you ask for "full code with [whatever]" then you're essentially asking someone to do _everything_ for you. Please be willing to research things autonomously (such as how to obtain the logcat).